# Why do we use integration to calculate the average of a function?

Tags: integration, average

What I think is that we need to sum up all the values on the curve and we can only do that by integration. Is that correct?

Comment: A better question is what does it mean to be the average of a function over a region?  How is that even defined?  I think if you look at a formal definition, this will answer your question immediately.

Comment: It is commonly known that $\bar{f}=\frac{\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\ dx}{b-a}$

Comment: I think the edit changed the meaning of the question.  "What is the meaning of the average of the function over an interval" is a trivial question, with a trivial answer given by dsillman2000. The original question was essentially "why do we define the average of a function over an interval using an integral"? In other words, why is this a reasonable definition? Even though the original question was not very well written, it was a valid question; I'm going to roll back the edit.

Comment: Personally, my intuitive definition of the integral of a function over a region is "the average value of the function in the region times the volume of the region".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we want
to get the average
of $f(x)$
for
$a \le x \le b$.

As a first estimate,
we might use
$A_2
=\dfrac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}
$.

Adding another point,
$A_3
=\dfrac{f(a)+f((a+b)/2)+f(b)}{3}
$.

If we use
$n$ points,
we get
$A_n
=\frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(a+k(b-a)/n)
$.

In the limit,
if it exists,
we get
$A
=\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n
=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(a+k(b-a)/n)
$.

If $f(x)$ is nicely behaved,
$\int_a^b f(x) dx
=\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n
$
where
$I_n
=\Delta\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(a+k\Delta)
$ and
$\Delta
=\Delta(a, b, n)
=\dfrac{b-a}{n}
$.

But,
$I_n
=\Delta\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(a+k\Delta)
=\dfrac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(a+k\dfrac{b-a}{n})
=(b-a)A_n
$,
so
$A_n
=\dfrac1{b-a}I_n
$.

Taking the limit,
the average value
is the integral
divided by the
length of the interval.